# sql: what does Max() -1 mean?

Tags: sql, t-sql

**I have some questions regarding Max()**

1. What does the following query mean?

   `SELECT MAX(X) -1 FROM T`
2. I learned that the syntax should be:
   `SELECT (MAX(X) -1) as max_minus_one FROM T`
   no?
3. Do aggregation function (i.e. `Max()`) must be followed by `GRUOP BY` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MAX(x) - 1` simply means the max value of x in the table minus one.

You can always use parenthesis and aliases (`as some_cool_name`) to make thing clearer, or to change names in the result. But the first syntax is perfectly valid.

You only need `GROUP BY` if you intend to select anything more that the aggregated value, like this for instance:

```
select
    userName,
    avg(age)
from
    users
group by
    userName
```

Comment: using the alias
would return a table with one column and one row: max_minus_one and the result value

while w/o alias I would simply get the result value - not in a table?


Am I correct?

Comment: The aggregate functions (avg, max, sum etc) and the *alias* are two entirely unrelated things. 
Using alias will *name* the otherwise unnamed result of an aggregate function which is useful in many cases. 
But the result from an `SELECT` statement is always a result set, not a table and not a scalar value (single value) even if it is just one row with one column.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(X) -1
```

and

```
SELECT (MAX(X) -1)
```

are the same.

In this case you do not need a GROUP BY since you are not selecting other non aggregated fields.

Answer (score 1):

That would mean "one less than the maximum value in column X". (a) No, that's adding some stuff. (b) No, not when you're selecting a single column like this.

Answer (score 1):

A. It taxes the maximum value and subtracts 1.

B. If it is only an agregate function, then no. If you specify another column, then you have to use it in GROUP BY.

Comment: if I specify two more columns, do I have to group bu col1, col2 ?

Comment: Yes, you need to group by all the columns that are not used in an aggregate function